# How to get output in Real Number instead of complex number?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I made the following code to solve any quadratic polynomial but I want the final output to be a Real Number (Either a whole number or a fraction) but I get Complex numbers like (3+0j). How to convert them?

Here is the Code:-

```
import cmath
a = float(raw_input("Enter the Coefficient of x^2 :- "))
b = float(raw_input("Enter the coefficient of x :- "))
c = float(raw_input("Enter the value of constant term or c :- "))

d = ((b*b) - (4*a*c))
if d < 0:
    print "There are no Real Roots of this equation"
else:
    x1 = (((-b) + cmath.sqrt(float(d))) // 2*a)
    x2 = (((-b) - cmath.sqrt(float(d))) // 2*a)

    if x1 == x2:
        print "x = ", x1
    else:
        print "x = ", x1, "or", x2
```

Desired Result:- I want the final result to be a Real Number(both Rational and irrational is allowed including fractions)(Like: 4, 4/3 or something like that).

Comment: Do you want *rational* numbers or *real* numbers?

Comment: What do you want to see for the root of x^2 + 2 = 0?

Comment: I have added the desired Output in the question itself

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/fractions.html

Comment: @Lucifer Your question (and its title)  starts off stating that you want rational answers but then ends stating that you want real ones.

Comment: I edited my question but forgot to edit that part. Sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply only print the real part, besides you have to devide by `2a`

```
x1 = (((-b) + cmath.sqrt(float(d))) / (2*a))
x2 = (((-b) - cmath.sqrt(float(d))) / (2*a))

if x1 == x2:
    print "x = ", x1.real
else:
    print "x = ", x1.real, "or", x2.real
```

Comment: He controls that only real solutions are accepted `if d < 0:`

Comment: No. I tried the above input again and got the output 24 which is totally not correct.

Comment: Using python 2.7 I get the correct result using only one `/` for devision and brackets around (2a)

Comment: Thank You. Your suggestion worked but I also used fraction lib which gave an exact fraction. `Fraction(Decimal(x1.real))`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a class like Complex and support imaginary solutions as well.
 Code taken from http://hplgit.github.io/primer.html/doc/pub/class/._class-solarized005.html

```
class Complex(object):
    def __init__(self, real, imag=0.0):
        self.real = real
        self.imag = imag

    def __add__(self, other):
        return Complex(self.real + other.real,
                   self.imag + other.imag)

    def __sub__(self, other):
        return Complex(self.real - other.real,
                   self.imag - other.imag)

    def __mul__(self, other):
        return Complex(self.real*other.real - self.imag*other.imag,
                   self.imag*other.real + self.real*other.imag)

    def __div__(self, other):
        sr, si, or, oi = self.real, self.imag, \ 
                     other.real, other.imag # short forms
        r = float(or**2 + oi**2)
        return Complex((sr*or+si*oi)/r, (si*or-sr*oi)/r)

    def __abs__(self):
        return sqrt(self.real**2 + self.imag**2)

    def __neg__(self):   # defines -c (c is Complex)
        return Complex(-self.real, -self.imag)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.real == other.real and self.imag == other.imag

    def __ne__(self, other):
        return not self.__eq__(other)

    def __str__(self):
        return '(%g, %g)' % (self.real, self.imag)

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Complex' + str(self)

    def __pow__(self, power):
        raise NotImplementedError\ 
          ('self**power is not yet impl. for Complex')
```

Comment: Sorry, but I recently started coding, hence I am not able to use the code you provided. Can you by any means tell me how to incorporate the above code in my code?